# Placement of const with clang-format

Tags: c++, clang-format

`clang-format` has tons of configuration options regarding whitespace and also some about code order (order of includes). Is it possible to reorder const-qualifiers so that they are placed to the right of the respective type?

Example: The declaration `const int x = 0;` should be formatted to `int const x = 0;`.

Comment: They've been adding rules to `clang-tidy` to transform code to follow the C++ Core Guidelines. Maybe you can request that when they add [NL.26](https://github.com/isocpp/CppCoreGuidelines/blob/master/CppCoreGuidelines.md#nl26-use-conventional-const-notation) they also add a rule to do the opposite.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From version 14.0 onwards, clang-format offers the option `QualifierAlignment` which can take the following values: `Leave`, `Left`, `Right` and `Custom`.

OP's request can thus be achieved with

```
clang-format -style="{QualifierAlignment: Right}" <file-name>
```

Documentation can be found [here](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html)

Edit: More information on values of `QualifierAlignment`

- Leave: clang-format will not touch qualifier placement
- Left: clang-format will align qualifiers left
- Right: clang-format will align qualifiers right
- Custom:

When `Custom` is used as the value for `QualifierAlignment`, the order from the clang-format option `QualifierOrder` is used. These two options have to then be used together, like so:

```
clang-format -style="{QualifierOrder: ['inline', 'static', 'type', 'const'], QualifierAlignment: Custom}" <file-name>
```

Edit2: It seems the prefix 'QAS' of QAS_Right, QAS_Left etc is not needed.

Comment: It seems as if `QualifierOrder` is a second way to change the order of qualifiers. Can you add it to your answer?

Comment: @pschill I will add more info on this, but I think it is not a second way to change the order. It is the order that will be used when used in combination with the argument `QAS_Custom`

Comment: This can also be expressed in a configuration file like so: https://stackoverflow.com/a/71695823/671509

Answer (score 10):

### EDIT: After `clang-format` version 14

As of `clang-format` version 14, the option for `QualifierAlignment` with value `Right` can be used. (See https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html for alternative values)

Set the following in the configuration file:

```
QualifierAlignment: Right
```

Warning:

> Setting `QualifierAlignment` to something other than `Leave`, COULD lead to incorrect code formatting due to incorrect decisions made due to clang-formats lack of complete semantic information. As such extra care should be taken to review code changes made by the use of this option.

### Before `clang-format` version 14

Unfortunately, such feature is not available according to the [documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html).

Answer (score 3):

This feature seems to be now in the works: https://reviews.llvm.org/D69764