# How to force east const in clang format?

Tags: c++, clang-format

Is there a flag in clang-format to change 'const west' to 'east const', so that the following:

```
void fun(const std::string &s);
```

would be reformatted to:

```
void fun(std::string const &s);
```

Comment: You can go through [the documentation](https://clang.llvm.org/docs/ClangFormatStyleOptions.html) and look for it. It's not too big of a list.

Comment: I don't think this is something clang format will ever handle. I think clang format works solely with the spaces between tokens, not with the ordering of tokens. This seems more suited for clang tidy. At any rate neither supports it at this time. Perhaps you could submit a feature request for it, or even a patch after discussing with them

Comment: <joke mode on> Don't join the dark side (east const)!!! :-)

Comment: To arms! They're storming through the gates!

Answer (score 17):

As of Clang-Format 14, there is `QualifierAlignment`. Add the following line to your *.clang-format* configuration file:

```
QualifierAlignment: Right
```

Answer (score 7):

AFAIK it isn't implemented yet, but there is [a feature request](https://bugs.llvm.org/show_bug.cgi?id=34220) in their bugtracker.